# Use value of 'AS ColumnName' later in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm making a stored procedure where I need to use a value that has been set earlier. I'm pretty bad at explaining this so I will use an example:

```
  CASE 
     WHEN ((select top 1 stuksweergeven from componenten
            where componentid = componentlink.componentid) = 1) and
          ((select opbrengstperkilo from componenten
            where componentid = componentlink.componentid) <> 0) THEN 
        amount1 * (select opbrengstperkilo from componenten
                   where componentid = componentlink.componentid)
     ELSE 
        amount1
  END AS Total,
Amount1 * Total *(SELECT dbo.SelectReceptenLinkGewicht(Componentid,0)) AS TotalWeight
```

I made a `CASE` that gives it outcome as Total. After that i would like to use Total to calcute the TotalWeight.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: your query is not reliable. Checking top 1 stuksweergeven for the value 1 can't be guaranteed to return the same result every time.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I would rather call it non-deterministic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that all expressions in `SELECT` list are evaluated in `all at once` manner. That's why you need to replicate your code. But you can create `subquery` for that or `cte` like:

```
with cte as(
             select Amount1,
                    ComponentID,
                    CASE 
                       WHEN ((select top 1 stuksweergeven from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid) = 1) and  ((select opbrengstperkilo from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid) <> 0) 
                       THEN amount1 * (select opbrengstperkilo from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid)
                       ELSE amount1
                    END AS Total
             from SomeTable)

select Total,
       Amount1 * Total *(SELECT dbo.SelectReceptenLinkGewicht(Componentid,0)) AS TotalWeight
from cte
```

Or:

```
select Total,
       Amount1 * Total *(SELECT dbo.SelectReceptenLinkGewicht(Componentid,0)) AS TotalWeight
from (
             select Amount1,
                    ComponentID,
                    CASE 
                       WHEN ((select top 1 stuksweergeven from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid) = 1) and  ((select opbrengstperkilo from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid) <> 0) 
                       THEN amount1 * (select opbrengstperkilo from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid)
                       ELSE amount1
                    END AS Total
             from SomeTable) t
```

Answer (score 2):

you can totally use `CROSS APPLY` to make things work for you. A very informative article: http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a derived table, something like:

```
select col1, col2
from (select c1 * c2 + c3 as col1,
             ... as col2
      from tablename)
where col1 = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use cross apply

```
SELECT 
  t.Amount1 * x.Total * dbo.SelectReceptenLinkGewicht(t.Componentid,0) 
    AS TotalWeight
FROM table t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 
    CASE 
     WHEN ((SELECT top 1 stuksweergeven from componenten
           WHERE componentid = componentlink.componentid) = 1) and
          ((SELECT opbrengstperkilo from componenten
           WHERE componentid = componentlink.componentid) <> 0) THEN 
           amount1 * (select opbrengstperkilo from componenten
           WHERE componentid = componentlink.componentid)
   ELSE 
     amount1
   END AS Total
) x
```